# Popup window in Angular2

Tags: angular, popup, popupwindow

Is there a way to create a non-modal popup window (not Alert, but a full fledged window which has Grids and other components inside) in Angular2 app or it absolutely must remain an SPA?

Some example how to do it would be useful (showing how to create it and pass data to/from main app).

TIA, 
Oleg.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
But since that is considered as loading new page, your data from the origin page will not be visible to that new popup window.
Alternatively you can save some data in Local storage and reuse it there, since popup window is part of the same domain as origin component (considering that you want to make it part of your origin app)

Also if that popup is some kind of edit/add form or profile view page, you can open a link with path or query parameter and inside your popup component you can read that data from url in ´ngOnInit´ and load something based on those params